# Drawing an arc between two points

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I was writing a java program to draw an arc.
Arc2D.Double(int x,int y,int width,int height,int startAngle,int arcAngle,int type);

Since, I'm not familiar with the mathematics behind drawing arc, I'm facing the problem.
Basically, what I want to is...I want to draw an arc between two points A and B. 
I want to draw an arc between the two lines depicting the angle between them. 
Some body please help me in calculating the startAngle and arcAngle.

Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Well, I found the answer to my scenario [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsZt4.png)...

Since, I don't have enough reputation to answer I'm writing it here....

Lets say that the center of the circle is (x0, y0) and that the arc contains your two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). Then the radius is: r=sqrt((x1-x0)(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)(y1-y0)). So:

```
int r = (int)Math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0));
int x = x0-r;
int y = y0-r;
int width = 2*r;
int height = 2*r;
int startAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*atan2(y1-y0, x1-x0));
int endAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*atan2(y2-y0, x2-x0));
graphics.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle);
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: You mention $x$ and $y$ coordinates as well as a width, a height, an startAngle an arcAngle and a type as input. What do they represent? And what is the angle between two points $A$ and $B$? Do you mean “with respect to the origin”, i.e. you draw a line through $A$ and the origin $(0,0)$ and a line through $B$ and the origin and that’s the angle?

Comment: I want to draw an arc at the corner of two intersecting lines.Type represents CHORD,OPEN,PIE types.x and y represents the top left corner of the bounding rectangle of the arc shape.

Comment: Intersection between two lines (corner) is the origin....

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Dot_product_and_generalisation) can help you.
In your case, $θ = \arccos \big(\tfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\big)$ gives you the angle $θ$ of the point $(a,b)$ to the (right ray of the) horizontal axis.

Comment: @K.Stm Thanks for your help.Well, I found the answer to my scenario here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196749/draw-arc-with-2-points-and-center-of-the-circle

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing as not having enough reputation to answer --- answering is how people *get* reputation. Not enough to comment, yes --- but not enough to answer? I don't think so. Try it!

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's about answering my Own question... Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 5 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: OK, sorry. ${}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I can answer it now
I found the answer...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196749/draw-arc-with-2-points-and-center-of-the-circle)

Lets say that the center of the circle is (x0, y0) and that the arc contains your two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). Then the radius is: r=sqrt((x1-x0)(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)(y1-y0)). So:

```
int r = (int)Math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0));
int x = x0-r;
int y = y0-r;
int width = 2*r;
int height = 2*r;
int startAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*atan2(y1-y0, x1-x0));
int endAngle = (int) (180/Math.PI*atan2(y2-y0, x2-x0));
graphics.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, endAngle);
```