# Draw an Arc - Given an angle and one segment

Tags: geometry

Is given an angle £ and an segment AB. Haw can I draw an arc from A to B such the central angle corresponding to it to be £ ?

Comment: This is how a program would do it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390272/drawing-an-arc-between-two-points

Comment: Have you seen questions similar to yours, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3094652/possible-to-draw-an-arc-semicircle-between-two-arbitrary-lines-without-bulgi)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find any point $C$ such that $\angle ACB = £/2$, then the $AB$ arc of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ will work.

You can do this by finding any two angles that add to $180^\circ - £/2$, and drawing one of them at $A$ and the other one at $B$, both with $AB$ as one of the angle legs, and let $C$ be where the two new angle legs intersect.